# How can I use a custom port (not default) for connecting a server and client using only telnet or FTP (in socket programming in C)?

Tags: c, network-programming, telnet

I read the link on [Beej's socket programming tutorial](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/singlepage/bgnet.html) which was really good. Although it didn't answer a question i was pondering since somehwere in the beginning of the tutorial and I'm not able to find the solution to this on Stackoverflow or google.

Since my question may seem ambiguous in the title, let me elaborate it so that it's more lucid.

I just want to be able to use any port (> 1024 of course) say 12345 and establish a TELNET connection or an FTP connection but not using the default ports (23, 21, etc). 
I have used the `getaddrinfo` function and used the `AF_INET` macro for IPV4, `SOCK_STREAM` for TCP and I could use `"telnet"` or port `23` for telnet in this function. But I want to know how do I (or can I use a custom port) use a custom port for the same. I have no problem with the code given in the tutorial link. I am new to this. So I'm just hoping that I can get some clarity with this.

PS: I am also reading Unix Network Programming (vol 1) although I just started and I can't seem to find it in that either.

Many thanks!

Comment: My understanding of the question is that here "you" are the *client*. Those ports specify where the *server* is listening on the remote side. Obviously you cannot use other ports unless the server has been explicitly configured to listen to those, which means you need to control it.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I want to write a code for both. If my server is using port 23, then it's using Telnet anyway. But I need to write a code for both and run it on two different machines (rather it should run)

Comment: Did you try simply changing the port number on server side? I am assuming that you are going to write the code.

Comment: The telnet command line you need is `telnet server port`. e.g. `telnet 192.168.0.1 1234`.

Comment: I'm aware of the telnet commands in unix to do this. But I want to know how to do so at the socket programming level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Then writing your own TCP client/server applications you are free to use any ports you like (aside the fact that you need root privileges to bind ports below 1024) and which are not used by the rest of the system. So you should bind to desired port/interface on server side  and use the same port for client application.

Comment: probably I'm not fully understanding what `bind` does. I understand that it _associates_ the port with a socket. Does that mean it just uses it's properties or _uses_ the port?

Comment: The bind function associates a local address with a socket.

Comment: So if I say I want the client to connect to "10.0.0.1" and port 12345 and I want this connection to use Telnet by default. I should `bind` port 12345 to 23 and `listen` for connections. 
so does this mean port 23 will be busy when there are incoming connections? (in case I need to use port 23 for different processes simultaneously - I know it's an unlikely scenario where I would be using many user defined ports as servers on one machine but just for the sake of "What if")

Comment: no.. you cannot bind ports between each other. and you cannot make a connection using 'something by default'. You should implement your own server doing some logic, listening for incoming connection on certain port and that's achieved using bind() system call, and then you write a client which connects to server using same port number.

Comment: I would suggest to check Unix Network Programming which you mentioned you are reading to get more structured picture how address/ports works. Thats actually a very good book

Comment: So I cannot ask a client to connect to port 12345 using Telnet? I can only listen on port 23? 
I am in the process of reading it and trying out some programs on my own. And this was something that I wanted to be clear about before proceeding. Thanks a ton!

Comment: you can use a Telnet as a client to connect to anything you like even to stackoverflow.com. But you should realise that Telnet is a client itself, so 'ask a client to connect to port using telnet' has no that much meaning.

Comment: Yes. I did mean that (since it's  protocol used). The telnet client program trying to connect to port 12345. 
Just realized that first part of the last comment didnt make much sense. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

Just bind your socket to that port number before calling `listen()`.

Comment: I apologize if I misunderstood the `bind()` function. So what you're saying that I am listening on say port 12345 at the server side. and I used `bind()` (binding it to port 23) before the `listen()` I can communicate using Telnet? 
And secondly, do I HAVE to use `bind()` in order to do this? (Mainly because I want to know if this would keep using up the two ports instead of just one, just so that it uses a particular standard. I just felt it sort of defeats the purpose of using two ports instead of one)

Comment: @ad3 I don't know what 'two ports instead of one' means. You create a socket, you bind to a port, you listen, clients connect to that port, you accept connections. I don't know what it is that you don't know here.

Answer (score 0):

probably you can enter entry based one new port in services file located in system32\etc\drivers